# PHP Zip can't be found

Tags: php

I'm running LEMP on a digitalocean droplet. We're running php v 7.2.19 on ubuntu 18.04.1.

I'm trying to install php-zip (`apt-get install php7.2-zip`) but am getting the error:

> apt-get install php7.2-zip
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: Unable to locate package php7.2-zip
>   E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.2-zip'
>   E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-zip'

I can't figure out why I can't install. Any suggestions?

Comment: What repos/ mirrors are you using? 17.04 is EOL since 2018-01

Comment: I'm not sure - sry I'm still learning a lot about this stuff. I booted with the DO one-click setup, which is "LEMP on18.04". Is there a way to check the repos/mirrors?

Comment: You are on 18.04, not 17.04. Try `sudo add-apt-repository universe && sudo apt update && sudo apt install php7.2-zip`. I assume your apt lists are wrong, check the files and entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Comment: that seems to have worked - thanks! I'm testing now but if y ou add an aswer I'll go ahead and accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The universe repository was missing. Solved by adding it via `sudo add-apt-repository universe` and then installing `php7.2-zip`.